# Examples of reputable journals in mathematics without impact factor? And is it good to publish in them?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, journals

I came across a journal which is reputable in terms of not being listed in Beall's list, but which according to [scimagojr](https://www.scimagojr.com/) and [clarivate](https://mjl.clarivate.com/) does not have an impact factor. The journal is [Journal of Numerical
Mathematics and Stochastics](http://www.jnmas.org/index.html).

My question is: are there other examples of such journals?
And is it advisable to publish in such journals?

> > **Motivation** The motivation behind this question is that a paper of mine has been accepted by the above journal, but I am afraid that it is not a good journal because it does not have an impact factor.

Comment: Just for standard typography: the punctuation precedes the spacing.

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean ? if there is any typo in my  question pleas fix it

Comment: That depends on your employer. I have been told that in some countries like Portugal and UK, researchers are evaluated using this kind of thing.

Comment: A good indication that the journal is not boggus is that it is indexed in MathSciNet and zbMATH. It does not to ask for payment from the authors, another good indication.

Comment: The reason let me ask the titled question, because I got acceptenence in that journal but I mixed between withdrawn case and continuation of publication because I was  afraid to be  is a spam journal

Comment: Is this paper similar to [A possible approach proof (*sic*) to proof the Riemann Hypothesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/32394)? Publication in an obscure journal does not imply that your proof is correct.

Comment: No, it is not the similar for that paper

Comment: Then why not put it up on arXiv so that everyone can see what it really is? Good journals all allow making preprints available like this.

Comment: I already put it

Comment: This is a question asking for career advice, masquerading as a technical question about research journals.

Comment: JNMAS claims that it is [listed in DOAJ](http://www.jnmas.org/Abstracting.html).  But a search at [DOAJ](http://doaj.org) does not find the journal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Newer journals often don't have impact factors because they don't have enough articles. And this can sometimes happen in odd ways. For example, the *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society* bifurcated into two pieces, where Part A is subscription journal that publishes as both print and electronic and is free to authors, while Part B is an open access electronic only journal that has a one-time author fee (although currently the AMS is waiving that fee for AMS members). However, the rating "agencies" view Part B of the Transactions as a separate new journal, despite the fact that authors don't have to choose until their paper is accepted whether to publish in A or B. That means that the open access Transactions Part B doesn't (or at least didn't last time I checked) have an impact factor, because it hasn't published enough articles yet. That may change soon, but it will also mean that the "open access Transactions Part B" will have an impact factor calculated using only the articles that appear in Part B. Whether that will lead to a larger or smaller impact factor than the regular Part A Transactions remains to be seen.

Comment: I do think Joe's answer is accurate... but/and, wow, all this stuff is so crazy, and not at all strongly connected to actual progress in our collective mathematical understanding. Not that I'm claiming that "the old days" were better... Sigh...

Comment: @paulgarrett In the old days, I guess reputation of journals was by some sort of collective consensus of the mathematical community. But ratig new journals was still an issue. I agree the idea of using some sort of metric to quantify "how good is journal X" is problematic, although the biggest issue, I feel, is that at first one gets a reasonable result, and then some people start using the numbers inappropriately (deans, promotion committees, etc), while other people start gaming the system. I feel that impact factor in math has reached this latter stage, so ranges from useless to pernicious.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, Journal which  dosn't have impact factor is not accepted for Doctorat thesis in my country  , However I got acceptenece in the linked journal in my question but am still affraid about the case of my paper which  it would be published there , Pleas explain me can I continue the process of publication or should I withdraw my paper from there as a reason it dosn't have impact factor ? Thank you

Comment: @JoeSilverman The only way to have good metrics is to invalidate them as valid once they get established. In a way a form of "inflation". A metric, when introduced is good and valid, but shrinks exponentially over the years. This means new metrics need to be introduced all the time. Right now, people try to uphold the value of the metric artificially, and that's what's wrong.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I can't make that decision for you. I will say that I think it is a bad idea to say that journals without an impact factor should not be allowed for doctoral theses or for promotions. On the other hand, there are more and more journals out there whose standards are very low (or non-existent, they'll publish anything if someone pays the page fees). So some standards are required. Someone mentioned MathSciNet. I know that they do a careful review of which journals to include, and are constantly re-evaluating their list. But I can't convince your country to change it's policy.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, Great reply , you are really convinced me , I should continue with that journal since it is covred by mathsci and it is free not payable .Really this enough to me to publish in it

Comment: @CaptainEmacs We seem to be in agreement. There's actually a principle (named after someone, but I've forgotten who) that quantifies this sort of "the reliability of a metric decreases at such and such a rate over such and such a time frame." I think it was formulated by an economist. Maybe someone else will know the exact reference.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Yes, I know precisely what you mean, but I also forgot - for now - the name. However, I suggest a more proactive approach; I suggest that this devaluation *be enacted* by decree, not just by "value creep". This is similar to the "Schwundgeld" idea - vanishing money that was brought up by Gesell; but on the level of metrics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law

Comment: @CaptainEmacs If we succeed in enacting a devaluation formula, will the value of the devaluation formula be itself subject to devaluation?

Comment: @TimothyChow Good question, but I do not think so, at least not much. The idea is that if there is a good metric, there is some inertia to it before it breaks, and the devaluation captures that inertia. Of course, the discovery/construction of new good metrics is now the new challenge, and the problem is that if - say - some central agency is tasked with that, there is always the possibility of meddling with and gaming the system; but that's an institutional, not a methodological issue. The devaluation simply counteracts the overfitting to the KPIs.